# NetBeans configurations

Tags: c++, netbeans, g++

I need help configuring my NetBeans to use C++. I'm now using it on Linux and the construction fails every time, no matter what the project, so I'm assuming it must have something to do with the compilers and makers installed.

[image: Compilators and makers installed]

Is there something I can change here?

Comment: how is anybody supposed to help when you don't tell anything about what the problem is?

Comment: the only thing appearing on the terminal is that the construction failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NetBeans select *Tools* -> *Plugins* -> *Settings* tab -> *Configuration of Update Centers* and install the latest version of the NetBeans Plugin Portal. The latest version of the NetBeans Plugin Portal is compatible with one of the later versions of g++ 8, 9 or 10 in your distribution's default repositories.

[image: NetBeans Plugin Portal]

Install the C/C++ plugin. In NetBeans, select *Tools* -> *Plugins*. Then in *Available Plugins* tab, in the C/C++ category, check the box for C/C++, then click *Install* to start the installation. Restart NetBeans before using the C/C++ plugin.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It was really the plugin, something must have gone wrong when I first tried to install it.